# How to configure AWS Chatbot to deliver useful messages from Beanstalk to Slack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, slack, aws-event-bridge, aws-chatbot

We have an Elastic Beanstalk deployment and wanted to receive events into our Slack channel. We setup EventBridge and Chatbot to deliver notifications. Everything works, except the notifications are useless, because Chatbot does not map the message detail only the detail type, which does not tell much. See the attached image of a notification (cropped to cut out the region/account info), the message is not too useful without telling us what was the actual change, which is in the event received by EventBridge and sent to SNS, but not mapped by Chatbot when sending to Slack.

[image: Chatbot Slack Notification]

Even their example test notification demonstrates the same problem:

[image]

I checked the [Chatbot documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/chatbot/latest/adminguide/related-services.html) where they claim support for multiple services via EventBridge. I checked [EventBridge documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-service-event.html) where they list Elastic Beanstalk among supported services.

I also subscribed and tested Health service notifications, which work just fine. See the example test notification below.

[image]

I could not find a way to configure Chatbot to do the right thing. I could write my own message transformer for certain events and call a Slack webhook instead of using Chatbot, but I wanted to avoid writing custom code here for now.

Does anyone know if it is possible to fix Beanstalk notifications that are sent from EventBridge to Chatbot then to Slack? Or is AWS working on supporting more service notifications and in the future this might start working as it should?

Thank you in advance.